# Passing C objects (CFFI) to .NET (Pythonnet)

Tags: python, c++, .net, python.net, python-cffi

Using Python, I would like to use C or C++ structs defined in a dll and pass them to .NET dll written in C#. The C or C++ dll is added using cffi, the .NET one is loaded using pythonnet.

The definition of the structs is identical in both dlls.

Here is a simple example for float2, of course reality is more complex :)

```
import sys
import clr
import numpy as np

sys.path.append('my_dot_net.dll')

#load the .NET dll
clr.AddReference("dot_net_dll")

from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()

#load C dll
lib = ffi.dlopen('c.dll')

# definition of a simple struct, there is an identical one in .NET
ffi.cdef('''typedef struct
            {
                float x;
                float y;
            } float2;''')

from dot_net_namespace import float2

#float2 type in dot net
dotnet_float2 = float2()
dotnet_float2.x = 1.0
dotnet_float2.y = 2.0

#float2 in the c dll
c_float2 = ffi.new("float2 *") # usually numpy array
c_float2.x  = 1.0
c_float2.y  = 2.0
```

Now I would like to e.g. create an array of the .NET data type or assign objects to the a struct available in .NET and assign the C type objects to that:

```
dot_net_float2_array = System.Array.CreateInstance(dot_net_float2, 100)
dot_net_float2_array[0] = c_float2 #does not work

dot_net_struct.xy = c_float2 #does not work
```

I get different error messages like

```
TypeError: Cannot convert <cdata 'float2[]' owning 8240 bytes> to dot_net_namespace.float2[]

'_cffi_backend.CDataOwn' value cannot be converted to dot_net_namespace.float2

TypeError: initializer for ctype 'float2' must be a list or tuple or dict or struct-cdata, not float2
```

I have no idea how to solve this. The real code I am working on should use structs that hold arrays of structs and I can't even get this simple example to run :)

Of course it is possible to copy the structs field by field, but is there a more convenient way? Is this possible at all?

Might it be possible to use `ffi.cast` or `ffi.buffer`?

Comment: You could write an interface in C#, and then use that interface in pythonnet.

Comment: But this would by like copying primitives of the structs field by field, right?
I would really prefer to solve this using casting or whatever, but I have no clue so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up passing pointers to .NET. They can be casted as described in my other question here. The full answer should become visible once my edit is reviewed and accepted.

[How to cast a pointer to a Python cffi struct to System.IntPtr (.NET)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860493/how-to-cast-a-pointer-to-a-python-cffi-struct-to-system-intptr-net)

After this [Marshal.PtrToStructure Method (IntPtr, Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to reassemble the structs in .NET.

Comment: I posted an answer to my question linked above.