# How to cast a pointer to a Python cffi struct to System.IntPtr (.NET)?

Tags: python, .net, python.net, python-cffi

I need to pass a System.IntPtr to a .NET function (Python with pythonnet). This pointer should refer to a struct created in cffi.

I found [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2005-July/000379.html):

```
from CLR.System import IntPtr, Int32
i = Int32(32)
p = IntPtr.op_Explicit(i)
```

This is what I tried so far

```
import clr
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()

custom_t = '''
            typedef struct
            {
                float x;
                 float y;
                 float z;

            } float3;
            '''

ffi.cdef(custom_t)

cfloat3 = ffi.new("float3 *")
cfloat3.x = 1.0
cfloat3.y = 2.0
cfloat3.z = 3.0
print(cfloat3)

from System import IntPtr

p = IntPtr.op_Explicit(id(cfloat3)) #works, sort of...
print(p)

#I would rather see something like
p2 = IntPtr.op_Explicit(ffi.addressof(cfloat3).value)
p3 = IntPtr(ffi.cast("float3*", cfloat3))
p4 = IntPtr(ffi.cast("void3*", cfloat3))

#type(_), ffi.typeof(_), ffi.typeof(_).kind, ffi.addressof()
```

But I am not sure if using [IntPtr.op_Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.intptr.op_explicit(v=vs.80).aspx) is the best solution. It looks a bit like workaround in combination with `id()` and I am pretty sure there is a better solution.

Comment: This is the p2 in my example, does not work. Or does it for you?

Comment: I found this: IntPtr is just a .NET type for void*. It doesn't imply any meaning by itself. No pointer type is associated with it even though its name sounds like "pointer to int", it is the equivalent of void* in C/C++.

Comment: Also found this in the cffi docs: To cast a pointer to an int, cast it to intptr_t or uintptr_t, which are defined by C to be large enough integer types. But something like `p = IntPtr(int(ffi.cast("intptr_t", ...)))` does also not work.

Comment: does this example with ctypes help? https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2013-January/001272.html

Comment: I found a similar example earlier, too. Will try that tomorrow. 
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2015-July/001672.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to use the `Overloads` method of `IntPtr`

```
from System import IntPtr, Int32, Int64
my_ptr = ffi.cast("intptr_t", my_c_struct)
cs_handle = IntPtr.Overloads[Int64](Int64(int(my_ptr)))
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550999/7919597) and [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2015-July/001672.html).

Here is a working example:

```
import clr
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()

custom_t = '''
            typedef struct
            {
                float x;
                 float y;
                 float z;

            } float3;
            '''

ffi.cdef(custom_t)

cfloat3 = ffi.new("float3 *")
cfloat3.x = 1.0
cfloat3.y = 2.0
cfloat3.z = 3.0
print(cfloat3)

from System import IntPtr, Int32, Int64

my_ptr = ffi.cast("intptr_t", cfloat3)
print(my_ptr)
print(ffi.typeof(my_ptr))
print(ffi.typeof(my_ptr).kind)
print(ffi.typeof(my_ptr).cname)
print(int(my_ptr))
print('hex', hex(int(my_ptr)))

#you don't need to cast to System.Int64 first, also works without:

#with casting the Python int to System.Int64
cs_handle = IntPtr.Overloads[Int64](int(my_ptr))
print(cs_handle)

#without casting the Python int to System.Int64
cs_handle = IntPtr.Overloads[Int64](Int64(int(my_ptr)))
print(cs_handle)

# using this workaround mentioned in the question also works
p = IntPtr.op_Explicit(int(my_ptr)) #works, sort of...
print('op_Explicit', p)

#careful: do not use the id() of the C structure, it is different and incorrect
print(cfloat3)
print(ffi.addressof(cfloat3[0]))
print('id(cfloat3)', id(cfloat3), hex(id(cfloat3)))
```

Some further info on what is happening above (found here and there):

> - C#'s IntPtr maps exactly to C/C++'s intptr_t.
> - intptr_t     integer type capable of holding a pointer
> - To cast a pointer to an int, cast it to intptr_t or uintptr_t, which are defined by C to be large enough integer types. [cffi doc with examples](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html)
> - IntPtr is just a .NET type for void*.
> - The equivalent of an unmanaged pointer in the C# language is IntPtr. You can freely convert a pointer back and forth with a cast. No pointer type is
>     associated with it even though its name sounds like "pointer to int",
>     it is the equivalent of void* in C/C++.
> - IntPtr(5) complains that `int/long' value cannot be converted to System.IntPtr`. It seems like it is trying to cast or something instead of calling the constructor. (found [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2013-January/001272.html))
> - Methods of CLR objects have an '_ *overloads* _', which will soon be deprecated in favor of iPy compatible Overloads, attribute that can be used for this purpose. (found [here](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#genericmethods))

Comment: Your second link is broken

Comment: Thanks, link fixed.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct support for CFFI inside Python.Net or vice-versa, so you need to cast the pointer from one library to an integer and reimport that integer into the other library.

From CFFI, `intaddr = ffi.cast("intptr_t", p)` will give you an integer.  Then you can probably do `IntPtr(intaddr)`.

Comment: I already tried that, see the comment to my question. But IntPtr still complained. Even when I imported the `System.Int64` or `System.Int32` data type from pythonnet and fed the casted integer to there and then the `Int64/32` to IntPtr. Don't have the code here at the moment. I can paste it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

FFI has an addressof function built in:

http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref.html#ffi-addressof

Comment: This is the p2 in my example, does not work. Or does it for you?

Comment: Right, sorry.  Looking into it further, it seems the code `ffi.new("float3 *")` actually returns a pointer already.  Are you sure you cant just use the variable cfloat3 as a pointer?

Comment: like `p4 = IntPtr(cfloat3)`?